property of linear functions and cubic functions
I know that:
If $f(x)=x-x_1$, then $f(x_1+t)+f(x_1-t)=0$ for all real number $t$.
If $f(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$, then $f(x_1+t)+f(x_1-t)+f(x_2+t)+f(x_2-t)+f(x_3+t)+f(x_3-t)=0$ for all real number $t$.
Are there other values of $n$ which satisfy $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\{(f(x_i+t)+f(x_i-t)\}=0$ where $f(x)=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)$, except $1$ and $3$?
I tested $n=4,\,5,\,6$ and now know it does not hold in these cases.
So I think no, and I tried to use mathematical induction from $n=4$. If $n=4$, it does not hold. Then the next step would be to prove that when it does not hold if $n=k$, then it also does not hold if $n=k+1$, where $k\geq4$.
But I have no idea. I cannot even start. I don't know how to make a link between $k$ and $k+1$. Is there any effective method to find(determine) at least one value of $t$ which satisfies
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\{(f(x_i+t)+f(x_i-t)\}\neq0$?
I tried writing $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^i$ and using Vieta's formula, but this is also too complicated.
Any help would be appreciated.
